# How to get query string values in YII without PATH format?

Tags: php, yii

I am having following url,

```
www.example.com/index.php?r=recommend/create&id=184?
title=Ruins%20of%20Mahabalipuram
&url=http://localhost/index.php/mediadetail/index/184
```

I need to **get title and url** which are query string parameters.

Has anyone worked on getting values in query string in Yii?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also the [getParam()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getParam-detail) method in CHttpRequest.

```
Yii::app()->request->getParam('title')
```

I've found it a valuable shortcut, since it checks both $_POST and $_GET and gives priority to $_GET, so you can use it to override post variables in the address URL. It also performs null checks and you can provide a default value in the second parameter.

The drawbacks are that you can't use it for arrays and maybe it's a little bit verbose (compared to $_GET['title']).

Answer (score 1):

Look the function [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-str.php), it would worked and if not, look [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-url.php) but it's not necessary for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

They'll automatically be available in your action as `$_GET` variables. Yii handles parsing them for you as part of the CHttpRequest object